# Why am I getting "URL.hostname is not implemented, js engine hermes" when supabase is intialized?

Tags: react-native, expo, supabase

I am building an expo project. So far I'm just trying to create the login/sign up auth logic. I want to use supabase. The project will load if there is no supabase initialization, but when supabase.js is not all commented out, I get the following error:

`ERROR  Error: URL.hostname is not implemented, js engine: hermes`

The supabase initialization is as follows:

```
import {createClient} from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabaseUrl = "...";
const supabaseKey = "...";

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);
```

Everything is installed correctly and I am using the latest versions of Supabase, expo, etc.

Comment: You can either use a polyfill (https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/8464#issuecomment-1221448428)for or use old js engine ```jsc```(https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-hermes/#switch-javascript-engine-on-a-specific-platform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an issue with RN and Supabase but there is a workaround until a fix can be implemented just add `react-native-url-polyfill` to your project and it should clear the error.

```
yarn add react-native-url-polyfill
```

Then import the package where the client is initialized:

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'

import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
```

Refer to the following issue for more information: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/8464#issuecomment-1221448428